# Uploading photos to facebook in a seperate php thread

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm building a gallery system, part of which imports and exports images from facebook.  The problem I'm having is that when you have a lot of source images to copy (~150), the user has to spend a lot of time looking at an inactive screen.

Does anyone know if you can send this operation to a background thread using Curl or HttpRequest?
Is there any special way you would have to handle the facebook auth?

Ideally, i'd like to post users back to a page saying that the images are on there way, but in the mean time can carry on with what they are doing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Write a script that does all the work. You can either executing via a scheduler, or using system/exec calls and run it as a background job.

```
exec('php /path/to/my/script.php &');
```

PHP wont wait for the script to finish. But it will continue to run in the background.

Comment: Hello,  thanks data sage for your suggestion, I did try this, but to no avail.  The problem is that i couldn't work out how to pass post and session data.

Comment: It would be a seperate process so it wouldnt have the data in post/session. You can either pass parameters and access them through $argv or save the data you need in a database and access it with the script.